# Как поменять стиль кнопки при нажатии

Tags: reactjs, button, react-native, style

у  меня 3 кнопки, как сделать чтобы менялся стиль у кнопки которую нажали, чтобы пользователь видел какая сложность была выбрана?

Желательно чтобы кнопка была отдельной компонентой и при желании можно было добавить еще один режим сложности, спасибо.

[image: экран приложения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете к Вашему элементу добавить атрибут `onclick` и вызвать функцию передав сам элемент DOM. Пример (html):

`<button onclick="Change(this)"></button>`

JavaScript:

```js
function Change(el){
  // Берем наш элемент, и делаем с ним что хотим (меняю цвет на красный)
  el.style.color = 'red';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это то, что вам нужно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код из видео:

```
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  var [ isPressEasy, setIsPressEasy ] = React.useState(false)
  var [ isPressMedium, setIsPressMedium ] = React.useState(false)
  var [ isPressHard, setIsPressHard ] = React.useState(false)

  var touchPropsEasy = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    underlayColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)', // backgroundColor кнопки
    style: isPressEasy ? styles.ButtonEasyPress : styles.ButtonEasy,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPressEasy(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPressEasy(true),
    onPress: () => console.log('Easy'),
  };
  var touchPropsEasyText = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    style: isPressEasy ? styles.TextPressEasy : styles.Text,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPressEasy(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPressEasy(true),
  };
  var touchPropsMedium = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    underlayColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
    style: isPressMedium ? styles.ButtonMediumPress : styles.ButtonMedium,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPressMedium(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPressMedium(true),
    onPress: () => console.log('Medium'),
  };
  var touchPropsMediumText = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    style: isPressMedium ? styles.TextPressMedium : styles.Text,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPressMedium(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPressMedium(true),
  };
  var touchPropsHard = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    underlayColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
    style: isPressHard ? styles.ButtonHardPress : styles.ButtonHard,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPressHard(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPressHard(true),
    onPress: () => console.log('Hard'),
  };
  var touchPropsHardText = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    style: isPressHard ? styles.TextPressHard : styles.Text,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPress(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPress(true),
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text {...touchPropsEasyText}>Easy</Text>
      <TouchableHighlight {...touchPropsEasy}>
      <Text style={styles.TextInButton}>1 to 10</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Text {...touchPropsMediumText}>Medium</Text>
      <TouchableHighlight {...touchPropsMedium}>
      <Text style={styles.TextInButton}>1 to 1000</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Text {...touchPropsHardText}>Hard</Text>
      <TouchableHighlight {...touchPropsHard}>
      <Text style={styles.TextInButton}>1 to 100</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(29, 29, 29)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  // По стандарту кнопки:
  ButtonEasy: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
  },
  ButtonMedium: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
  },
  ButtonHard: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
  },

  // По стандарту текст:
  TextInButton: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 8
  },
  Text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 20
  },

  // Нажатые кнопки:
  ButtonEasyPress: {
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#00FF7F',
  },
  ButtonMediumPress: {
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#42aaff',
  },
  ButtonHardPress: {
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#FA8072',
  },

  //Текст при нажатых кнопках:
  TextPressEasy: {
    color: '#00FF7F',
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 20
  },
  TextPressMedium: {
    color: '#42aaff',
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 20
  },
  TextPressHard: {
    color: '#FA8072',
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 20
  }
});
```

Упрощенный код для вашего примера:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  var [ isPressEasy, setIsPressEasy ] = React.useState(false)
  var [ isPressMedium, setIsPressMedium ] = React.useState(false)
  var [ isPressHard, setIsPressHard ] = React.useState(false)

  var touchPropsEasy = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    underlayColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)', // backgroundColor кнопки
    style: isPressEasy ? styles.ButtonPress : styles.Button,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPressEasy(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPressEasy(true),
    onPress: () => console.log('Easy'),
  };
  var touchPropsEasyText = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    style: isPressEasy ? styles.TextPress : styles.Text,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPressEasy(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPressEasy(true),
  };
  var touchPropsMedium = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    underlayColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
    style: isPressMedium ? styles.ButtonPress : styles.Button,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPressMedium(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPressMedium(true),
    onPress: () => console.log('Medium'),
  };
  var touchPropsMediumText = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    style: isPressMedium ? styles.TextPress : styles.Text,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPressMedium(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPressMedium(true),
  };
  var touchPropsHard = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    underlayColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
    style: isPressHard ? styles.ButtonPress : styles.Button,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPressHard(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPressHard(true),
    onPress: () => console.log('Hard'),
  };
  var touchPropsHardText = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    style: isPressHard ? styles.TextPress : styles.Text,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPress(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPress(true),
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text {...touchPropsEasyText}>Easy</Text>
      <TouchableHighlight {...touchPropsEasy}>
      <Text style={styles.TextInButton}>1 to 10</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Text {...touchPropsMediumText}>Medium</Text>
      <TouchableHighlight {...touchPropsMedium}>
      <Text style={styles.TextInButton}>1 to 1000</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Text {...touchPropsHardText}>Hard</Text>
      <TouchableHighlight {...touchPropsHard}>
      <Text style={styles.TextInButton}>1 to 100</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(29, 29, 29)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  // По стандарту кнопки:
  Button: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
  },

  // По стандарту текст:
  TextInButton: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 8
  },
  Text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 20
  },

  // Нажатые кнопки:
  ButtonPress: {
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#42aaff',
  },

  //Текст при нажатых кнопках:
  TextPress: {
    color: '#42aaff',
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 20
  }
});
```

**Чтобы вынести как отдельный компонент:**

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Botton from './Button'

export default function App(){
  return(
    <View style={styles.background}>
      <Botton/>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(29, 29, 29)'
  },
})
```

Button.js:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

export default function Button() {
  var [ isPressEasy, setIsPressEasy ] = React.useState(false)

  var touchPropsEasy = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    underlayColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)', // backgroundColor кнопки
    style: isPressEasy ? styles.ButtonPress : styles.Button,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPressEasy(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPressEasy(true),
    onPress: () => console.log('Easy'),
  };
  var touchPropsEasyText = {
    activeOpacity: 1,
    style: isPressEasy ? styles.TextPress : styles.Text,
    onHideUnderlay: () => setIsPressEasy(false),
    onShowUnderlay: () => setIsPressEasy(true),
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text {...touchPropsEasyText}>Easy</Text>
      <TouchableHighlight {...touchPropsEasy}>
      <Text style={styles.TextInButton}>1 to 10</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  // По стандарту кнопки:
  Button: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'rgb(90, 90, 90)',
  },

  // По стандарту текст:
  TextInButton: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 8
  },
  Text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
    width: 150,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },

  // Нажатые кнопки:
  ButtonPress: {
    width: 150,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#42aaff',
  },

  //Текст при нажатых кнопках:
  TextPress: {
    color: '#42aaff',
    fontSize: 30,
    width: 150,
    textAlign: 'center',
  }
});
```

Comment: Да, это почти то что мне нужно, только как мне вынести кнопку в отдельный компонент для повторного использования, и сделать так чтобы кнопка оставалась подсвеченной после того как её нажали, а когда нажали другую стала подсвеченной только она?

Comment: Добавил пример того, как вынести в отдельный компонент.
По поводу второго - не знаю как сделать с отдельными компонентами, может быть надо props экспортировать еще, не знаю. Если все 3 кнопки в одном компоненте, тогда, возможно можно сделать.